# Removing data points above/below value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am trying to remove all the values outside the range [-500,500], I simply want to remove the particular colum/"Index" values that exceed this limit. I have tried a lot of different things, but nothing really seems to work. I have tried using this code, but then I get the error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYzNo.png)

```
File "C:\Users\Jeffs.spyder-py3\kplr006779699.py", line 30, in data = data[data['0'] < abs(500)]

File "C:\Users\Jeffs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in getitem indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

File "C:\Users\Jeffs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 354, in get_loc raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: '0'
```

which i'm guessing is because the column named '0' doesn't have really have a column name.

```
from astropy.io import ascii
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pandas as pd

#Data from KIC 6779699

df = ascii.read(r'G:\Downloads\kplr006779699_kasoc-ts_llc_v1-2.dat')

# print(df)

x_Julian_data = df['col1']

x_data_raw = (x_Julian_data-54000)*86400 #Julian time to seconds: 60*60*24
data = np.linspace(0, 65541, num = int(65541) , endpoint = True)
y_data_raw = df['col2'] #Relative flux ppm
for i in range (65541-2):#Cleaning up data
    data[i+1] = y_data_raw[i+1]-.5*(y_data_raw[i]+y_data_raw[i+2])
data[0] = 0
data[65540] = 0
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = data[data['0'] < abs(500)]

plt.plot(x_data_raw, data)
plt.xlim([1.1E8,1.25E8])
plt.ylim([-500,500])
```

I can't quite get it to work, even if I try using a definition.
Is there an easier way to approach this?

Comment: Did you mean, remove all the rows for which a particular column value is outside the range [-500,500]?

Comment: Yes I want to remove all the data points that exceed that limit

Comment: Try removing the quotes from '0': data = data[data[0] < abs(500)]

Comment: That gives me:
runfile('C:/Users/Jeffs/.spyder-py3/kplr006779699.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jeffs/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Jeffs\.spyder-py3\kplr006779699.py", line 30, in <module>
    df.head()

AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: can you print the data frame immediately after creation?  data = pd.DataFrame(data) ; print(data).  That'll show what the dataframe shape is with column names

Comment: 0
0        0.000000
1      -51.630961
2     -290.618820
3      150.029810
4     -113.142182
          ...
65536   61.267915
65537  196.403178
65538  128.984613
65539 -178.875742
65540    0.000000

[65541 rows x 1 columns]

Answer (score 0):

"data" is a numpy array (created using np.linspace), so you can filter it by value *before you create the data frame:

```
data = data[data < abs(500)]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a_useful_column_name'])
```

(while debugging consider using a new variable name for the DataFrame)

Comment: Note that you'll have trouble plotting x_data_raw vs. data since they will be different length vectors

Comment: that gives me
  File "C:\Users\Jeffs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 399, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (65541,) and (65490, 1)